# How to make ALT+... shortcuts work in Eclipse Juno 4.2?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I updated to Eclipse Juno 4.2 and I discovered that some custom shortcuts I used in 3.7 do not work anymore.

For example, I set up `Alt+E` as "Delete Previous Word" when Editing Text. This does not work. I suspect there is some interference from the File menu (Alt + E originally brings up the Edit menu). Anyone know how to make this shortcut work?

Comment: If it used to work, I'd open a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=UI

Comment: Bug filed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385302

Comment: I'm experiencing the same defect in Juno 4.2.1: 
the hotkeys `Alt-C` for Commit and `Alt-U` for Update to HEAD are shown in the Team-menu of the Project, but have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 4.2 bug filed: [bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385302](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385302)